# Do equivalence relations work in the "not" case?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, equivalence-relations

I'm trying to write a proof involving equivalence relations. However, I'm not entirely sure my assumptions are valid.

We know for equivalence relations that $$A \sim B \implies B \sim A$$ $$A \sim B \text{ and } B \sim C \implies A \sim C$$

Does it follow that $$A \not \sim B \implies B \not \sim A$$ and $$A \not \sim C \implies A \not \sim B \text{ or } B \not \sim C?$$

I want to prove that

> If $f: A \to B$ and the range of $f$ is uncountable, then the domain of $f$ is uncountable.

Two sets $A_0$ and $B_0$ are equivalent if there exists a bijection between them, which we define a set to be countable if there exists a bijection between the set and the natural numbers.

Here's what I tried:

**PROOF:** Suppose the domain of $f$, $A$ is countable. Then $A \sim \mathbb N$. Since the range of $f$ is uncountable and the range of $f$ is a subset of $B$, this implies that $B$ is also uncountable. Thus, we have $$A \sim \mathbb N \tag{$A$ is countable}$$ $$B \not \sim \mathbb N \tag{$B$ is not countable}$$ $$A \not \sim B,$$ because one is countable, and the other is not, so there does not exist a bijection between the two. $$A \not \sim B \not \sim \mathbb N$$ $$A \not \sim \mathbb N \not \sim B,$$ which is a contradiction since we assumed $A$ is countable $\implies A \sim \mathbb N$.

Are the last two steps valid? I feel like they contradict the contrapositive of the transitive property.

Comment: Your first two statements with the negations are exactly the contrapositive of the first properties of equivalence relations. Remember that $P\Rightarrow Q$ is equivalent to $\neg Q\Rightarrow \neg P$ (its contrapositive), so assuming these is correct. After that you are making the following mistake: $A\not\sim B\not\sim \mathbb{N}$ does not imply $A\not \sim\mathbb{N}\not\sim B$, in the same say that $2\neq 3\neq 1+1$ does not imply $2\neq 1+1$

Comment: That example helps me understand why it's not valid. Thanks so much!

Comment: btw.: the negation of an equivalence relation is an [apartness relation](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/apartness+relation) (see "2. Definitions / Concrete")